# orderby () containing numbers and letters

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, linq-to-sql, sql-order-by

I want to order an array containing numbers and letters in an ascending order
the values are stored as a string in a DB.

This is the list I have

```
4B
1A
1
1B
2
4C
4
```

and want them to order like this where numbers are ascending followed by letters alphabetically.

```
1
1A
1B
2
4
4B
4C
```

So far I tried

```
 allScenes.OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.SceneNumber)).ToList()
```

and

```
 allScenes.OrderBy(x => Convert.int.parse(x.SceneNumber)).ToList()
```

but both don't work because of the letters after the number.
Any idea how I can make this work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given your example data where the first number is always a single digit:

```
allScenes.OrderBy(x => x.SceneNumber).ToList()
```

If you can possibly have multi-digit numbers, please provide them and where you want them in the sort order.

This is one way to sort multiple digit numbers:

```
var allScenes = new[]{
  new {SceneNumber="4B"},
  new {SceneNumber="1A"},
  new {SceneNumber="1"},
  new {SceneNumber="1B"},
  new {SceneNumber="2"},
  new {SceneNumber="14"},
  new {SceneNumber="4C"},
  new {SceneNumber="14A"},
  new {SceneNumber="200"},
  new {SceneNumber="200A"},
  new {SceneNumber="200B"}
  };
var nums="0123456789".ToCharArray();
var result=allScenes
  .OrderBy(x=>x.SceneNumber.LastIndexOfAny(nums))
  .ThenBy(x=>x.SceneNumber);
```

Results:

```
1 
1A 
1B 
2 
4B 
4C 
14 
14A 
200 
200A 
200B
```

The database may not be able to convert the LastIndexOfAny function to something SQL-like, so you may need to do an .ToList() before the .OrderBy():

```
var nums="0123456789".ToCharArray();
var result=allScenes
  .ToList()
  .OrderBy(x=>x.SceneNumber.LastIndexOfAny(nums))
  .ThenBy(x=>x.SceneNumber);
```

Comment: I indeed have mult-digit numbers in the list as well such as 10 and 10B up all the way till 200 and 200C. I would like to keep the list ascending. first the single digits then the double and then the triple followed by a letter in alphabetical order

Comment: Updated answer to handle multiple digit numbers.

Answer (score 0):

**Very simple**

```
string[] allScenes = {"4B","1A","1","1B","2","4C"};

var result = allScenes.OrderBy(x => x.First()).ThenBy(x => x.Last());
```

Answer (score 0):

As values are stored as `string` into the database you just have to write `OrderBy(e=> e)`.

The code below proves this works:

```
string[] items = {"4B", "1A", "1", "1B", "2", "4C", "4"};
items.OrderBy(e=> e)
```

Answer (score -2):

I also have a similar issue but bit difference as below example:

```
 "A4B", "1A1", "123", "1B45", "2", "4C", "4-A2";
```

Letter or special chars might be anywhere in string list, but need to sort only by numbers.
**Expected result:**

```
2, A4B, 4C, 1A1, 4-A2, 123, 1B45.
```

Comment: this is not an answer

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34690829)